# gdx file is not created when trying to export data from excel to gams

Tags: optimization, gams-math

I'm trying to export data from Excel to GAMS and I'm using the next code for this aim:

```
Set c row labels /c1*c10/
    x column labels /x1*x2/;

Parameter d(c,x);

$call GDXXRW Data.xlsx trace=3 par=d rng=Sheet1!a1 cdim=9 xdim=1
$GDXIN Data.gdx
$LOAD d
$GDXIN

Display d;
```

The directory of the Excel file is as follows:

*gamsdir\projdir\Data.xlsx*

But when it runs, the following errors occur:

*Msg : No such file or directory for gamsdir\projdir\Data.gdx.*

*Unable to open gdx file for $GDXIN*

*GDXIN file not open - ignore the rest line*

What could be the reason for this? Why isn't the gdx file created?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons. The most likely one is that the GDX file does not exist because there was an error calling `gdxxrw`. What does the log of `gdxxrw` say? In general, I would suggest checking the errorLevel after any `$call ...` to ensure that this succeeded before you continue. In your example, you could do it like this:

```
$call.checkErrorlevel GDXXRW Data.xlsx trace=3 par=d rng=Sheet1!a1 cdim=9 xdim=1
```